# $timeout not changing variable in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am working on a button and trying to shake it on clicking it if the form fields above it are invalid.

Here is my code for the controller :-

```
if(valid){.. do valid stuff here ..}

else{
console.log(this.shakeNotValid);
        // SHAKE ANIMATION
        this.shakeNotValid = true;

        $timeout(function() {
            this.shakeNotValid = false;
        } , 500);
}
```

No where else is this.shakeNotValid is defined or assigned.

The console line returns me undefined for the first time and the button shakes but subsequently it keeps returning me true again and again and doesnt shake.

In the html I am assigning a class to the button like this :-

```
        <div ng-click="main.mClick()" 
        ng-class="{isDisabled: !main.isValidContact && main.showContactCard, 
        isShaking: main.shakeNotValid}">
```

What I want is that this button can shake multiple times until all becomes valid as and when the user clicks.

Some help please, thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that `this` in `this.shakeNotValid = true` and `this` in `this.shakeNotValid = false` are two different objects.

If I were you, I'd try to change your code the following way and try it out:

```
if(valid){.. do valid stuff here ..}

else {
        _this = this;  
        console.log(_this.shakeNotValid);
        // SHAKE ANIMATION
        _this.shakeNotValid = true;

        $timeout(function() {
            _this.shakeNotValid = false;
        } , 500);
}
```

Comment: It might also be useful to read about `this` binding, as it is exactly the case we're facing here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind . It shows the way these issues can also be addressed and gives better understanding of why your variant didn't work.